# Java pattern for [j-*]

Tags: java, regex

Please help me with the pattern matching. I want to build a pattern which will match the word starting with `j-` or `c-` in the following in a string (Say for example)

```
[j-test] is a [c-test]'s name with [foo] and [bar]
```

The pattern needs to find `[j-test]` and `[c-test]` (brackets inclusive).

### What I have tried so far?

```
String template = "[j-test] is a [c-test]'s name with [foo] and [bar]";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[[*[j|c]\\-\\w\\-\\+\\d]+\\]");
Matcher m = patt.matcher(template);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

And its giving output like

```
[j-test]
[c-test]
[foo]
[bar]
```

which is wrong. Please help me, thanks for your time on this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a character class, you don't need to use alternation to match `j` or `c`. Character class itself means, match any single character from the ones inside it. So, `[jc]` itself will match either `j` or `c`.

Also, you don't need to match the pattern that is after `j-` or `c-`, as you are not bothered about them, as far as they start with `j-` or `c-`.

Simply use this pattern:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[[jc]-[^\\]]*\\]");
```

To explain:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?x)      "   // Embedded flag for Pattern.COMMENT
                             + "\\[       "   // Match starting `[`
                             + "    [jc]  "     // Match j or c
                             + "    -     "     // then a hyphen
                             + "    [^    "     // A negated character class
                             + "       \\]"        // Match any character except ] 
                             + "    ]*    "     // 0 or more times
                             + "\\]       "); // till the closing ]
```

Using `(?x)` flag in the regex, ignores the whitespaces. It is often helpful, to write readable regexes.

Comment: thanks for your answer Rohit, it worked great +1. Patterns are Greek for me, can you please explain what does `[^\\]]*` mean? I understood the rest. Otherwise can you please guide me to some useful resources?

Comment: @sanbhat Just added an explanation.